# Creating a convex hull object that covers disjoint objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path, gradient, fill

I am trying to freeform gradient fill this implied curved teardrop. However, when I compound path the objects freeform gradient doesn't work (see image below). My next idea was to create an object that encompasses all these objects, freeform gradient that, and then use these objects as a clipping mask. While this works for one, it overlaps with the other two teardrops which would get their own colors. How do I create an object (like a convex hull) that barely just encompasses these disjoint objects and so to speak "draws the full implied path" ? I also tried the shapebuilder tool with large enough gap detection and it joins them but not at the boundary... Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: use shabebuilder to rebuild the shape. Essentially you cant just say that something is a compound path and assume ot works as the compound path also needs to considt of correctly valid parts. If the dont then the results are unpredictable. You should be able to rebuild this with shapebuilder in a minute or 2

Answer (score 0):

Draw the circular shape with swirls (=Samtaegeuk) as a separate background object group.  Fill the swirls with colors or gradients as you like.

If it's for some reason needed you can see how to draw the Samtaegeuk or at least something quite closely resembling in this old discussion:   [How to draw Samtaegeuk (yin-yang symbol but with three swirls, each a different colour)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160978/how-to-draw-samtaegeuk-yin-yang-symbol-but-with-three-swirls-each-a-different)

Draw the embellished 2-triangle star symbol in front of the Samtaegeuk and set its colors fully independently.

Comment: Thanks for the information about the Samtaegeuk! I didn't know about this before. I made this using GeoGebra based on an islamic art pattern and exported into Illustrator. Technically I could go back and export those two shapes separately.

Comment: @SridharSrinivasan OK. I have never before heard nor seen the 3-swirl background symbol is an Islamic art pattern. I have thought Islamic art patterns were based on straight lines and circular arcs. But your Geogebra construction of it would be an useful new answer in the linked Samtaegeuk -discussion. The existing answers are probably all too poor (wrong look, utterly complex or need drawing skills), because none of them has got the accepted mark.

Comment: thanks! It is not an exact reproduction, Originally it was two triangle and circle set on a [bowl](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/456261)(which was made in afghanistan, 12th C) and made my own deviations on it. So it may or may not be fully islamic art. Regardless, I went back to GeoGebra and realized that I actually made it piece-wise with 3 curves, so am trying to figure out a parametric way. I will make an entry in the other question once I have a succinct formulation.

Comment: Although, Islamic art tends to get less regular and more squiggly the later it gets and with more cross-pollination with other cultures, for example [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamsa#/media/File:Rosette,_Titles_of_Shah_Jahan.jpg) [2](https://www.baytalfann.com/post/the-blue-tiles-of-uzbekistan)